# Calling functions within case pattern matching is illegal pattern?

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

```
-module(erltoy).
-compile(export_all).

isFive(5) -> true;
isFive(_) -> false.

foo(X) ->
 case X of
  isFive(X) -> true;
  3 -> false;
  _ -> nope
end.



1> c(erltoy).
erltoy.erl:9: illegal pattern
error
```

Can I not call functions as part of the pattern match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**isFive(X) -> true;** contains expression's which can't be computed to a constant at compile time and thus is not a valid [pattern](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#pattern) as a result. An arithmetic expression can be used within a pattern if it meets both of the following two conditions:

- It uses only numeric or bitwise operators.
- Its value can be evaluated to a constant when complied.

See this Example from the Erlang reference manual

```
case {Value, Result} of
    {?THRESHOLD+1, ok} -> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

to complete @byaruhaf answer, the left part of a case clause doesn't need to be a constant when **compiled**. the following code is valid, and obviously, `Temp` is not known at compile time (but foo(5) evaluates to nope!).

```
-module(erltoy).
-compile(export_all).

isFive(5) -> true;
isFive(_) -> false.

foo(X) ->
 Temp = isFive(X),
 case X of
  Temp -> true;
  3 -> false;
  _ -> nope
end.
```

It is even not necessary that the left part is bound at execution time, for example, this is also valid, and there `I` is unbound before the case evaluation, and bound during the pattern matching:

```
get_second_element_of_3_terms_tuple_if_pos_integer(X) ->
  case X of
    {_,I,_} when is_integer(I), I>0 -> {true,I};
    _ -> false
  end.
```

The left part of a case must be a valid pattern with an optional guard sequence.

A valid pattern is an erlang term that may contains unbound variables, it may also contain arithmetic expressions if they respect the 2 conditions

- It uses only numeric or bitwise operators.
- Its value can be evaluated to a constant when complied.

the definition of a guard sequence is given [there in erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id84508)

A final remark, the usual erlang way to code the kind of test function given in your example is to use different function heads, just as you do for isFive/1 definition.